# Is there any tool or somehow to make a OpenStreetMap editor which can manage multi layer in it?

Tags: openstreetmap, basemap, leaflet-draw, map-drawing, map-editor

I need to build a web application that could draw, edit, import, export,.. map using OSM data. In that, I could add layers and manage like tree form. The layer can be toggled on/off on the map to edit.

```
ex: - building
      + school
      + hospital
      + house
    -way
      +subway
      +highway
```

I tried some editor like iD but it not like what I want.
Does anybody know any tool or any solution to create something like this?